# How do I read lines from a text file in the order presented using windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file, formatting

I have a text file that looks like this

```
number 1
some junk goes here
fruit: apple
number 2
some stuff goes here
fruit: banana
number 3
some stuff goes here
fruit: orange
```

My script looks like this

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set input_file=testfile.txt

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (
    'findstr " 1 2 3" %input_file%'
) do echo      %%a

for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (
    'findstr "fruit" %input_file%'
) do echo      %%b
```

My current code is giving me this

```
1
2
3
fruit: apple
fruit: banana
fruit: orange
```

How do I get the output formatted like this?

```
1
fruit: apple
2
fruit: banana
3
fruit: orange
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tokens and delims options of the FOR command to your advantage.  Then use an IF command to determine which line it is processing.

```
@echo off

set input_file=testfile.txt

for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%G in ('findstr /RIC:"number [1-9]*" /IC:"fruit:" %input_file%') do (
    IF /I "%%G"=="number" echo %%H
    IF /I "%%G"=="fruit:" echo %%G %%H
)
```

Output

```
C:\Users\Squashman\Desktop>so.bat
1
fruit: apple
2
fruit: banana
3
fruit: orange
```

Comment: I would not worry what data may be contained as a possible second token, allow it to be anything or nothing, then use an if / else as oposed to two `if`'s: `@(For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:"^number *" /C:"^fruit: *" "testfile.txt" 2^>NUL') Do @If /I "%%G" == "fruit:" (Echo %%G %%H) Else Echo(%%H) & Pause`

Answer (score 0):

The example code you posted does not provide the result you have shown.

I was still skeptical on posting an answer as I am not 100% on what your actual requirements are, but I thought, given the current example, why not.

```
@echo off
set "inputfile=testfile.txt"
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('type "%inputfile%"') do (
    echo %%j | findstr /RC:"[0-9]"
    echo %%i %%j | findstr "fruit"
)
```

It might be far from what you want, but given the current examples, this is all I can assist with right now.

The idea of this answer is really to demonstrate that we use one loop, and not two. The way you attempted it would create the first set then the next which is obviously not what you required.

Comment: I edited the sample code to include setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion on the second line. I hope that makes it a little clearer. I figured it must be one loop with multiple commands, but your example doesn't work for me. I get "The syntax of the command is incorrect" with your code.

Comment: Without doing funny edits, copy my code again and try, you cannot get syntax errors with it as is. anyway, your edit doesn't make it more clear. `delayedexpansion` is used to expand at execution time which in this case does nothing for the cause. There are still 2 for loops which will cause the issue. The first loop will complete providing the numeric result, then the second which will provide the fruit result, so you need to run it in a single loop, as demonstrated here.